# Cannot copy an image due to mysterious error about EC2 BillingProduct code

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I am attempting to copy an EC2 image for the purpose of encrypting it.

The command line I issue is:

```
$ aws ec2 copy-image --name encrypted-kafka-201707121432 \
  --source-region ap-southeast-2 --encrypted --source-image-id ami-2a617249 \
  --region ap-southeast-2
```

This leads to the following error being emitted:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyImage operation:
  Images with EC2 BillingProduct codes cannot be copied to another AWS account.
```

I have looked around and I understand that this error is typically seen when copying Windows AMIs (e.g. [here](http://blog.open-tribute.org/2017/04/18/ami-copy-failed-billingproduct/)) and it is similar to this issue on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763041/issue-when-copy-ami-owned-by-another-account)).

However, this image is not from the Marketplace, and it is not a Windows AMI, and it does not have any ProductCodes in it:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-2a617249 --region ap-southeast-2 \
    --query '.Images[].ProductCodes'
[]
```

Compare this to another one that does:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-00280263 --region ap-southeast-2 \
    --query '.Images[].ProductCodes'
[
  {
    "ProductCodeType": "marketplace",
    "ProductCodeId": "dsli9z1o9amfv5g2hsmdj1pph"
  }
]
```

The image was baked using Packer.

I am out of ideas. Why is this happening - am I doing something wrong, or is this undocumented behaviour?

Comment: Was the instance generated from an AMI of the Marketplace instance, or is it in any way associated with a Marketplace instance? See also https://serverfault.com/questions/775946/aws-encrypted-ebs-boot-volumes-for-windows-instances and http://blog.open-tribute.org/2017/04/18/ami-copy-failed-billingproduct/

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, i.e. unless I have been misled, no. I guess to rule this out I would need to fully do all upstream AMI bakes myself, or is there a way of testing?

Comment: Turns out the answer is "yes" after all. Full explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that a descendent of this AMI did come from the Amazon Marketplace.

A simplified version of the baking pipeline is:

Account A:

Marketplace AMI (ami-xxxxxxxx) -> packer build (ami-yyyyyyyy) -> share to Account B

Account B:

I then issued:

```
aws ec2 copy-image --encrypted --source-image ami-yyyyyyyy
```

And received:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyImage operation:
  Images with EC2 BillingProduct codes cannot be copied to another AWS account.
```

From account B I could check the owner, namely the Account that shared it with me:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images --image-id ami-yyyyyyyy --region ap-southeast-2 \
>   --query 'Images[0].OwnerId'
```

This returned the 16-digit account ID of Account A.

At this point it is helpful to understand that baking an AMI using Packer causes the product codes to be *apparently* lost. However, those product codes remain, and Amazon support can see them. It requires a call to Amazon support to confirm this part.

To work around, I now maintain a script [encrypt_ami](https://github.com/alexharv074/encrypt_ami) in Python or Bash (AWS CLI) that can be used.

Comment: So you share the image, spin it up, and create your copy from the running instance, rather than being able to just make a copy of the image.